# Validating Dynamically added controls in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, telerik, dynamic

I am trying to get validation to work for my very first ASP.NET MVC application.  My problem is that all my controls were dynamically created.  I have a Telerik tabstrip that has tabs that were dynamically (or programmatically) added.  Each tab has a partial view with controls.  The model that those controls map to is an Entity Framework model.  I have decorated the model properties with annotations like “[Required]” (from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;) and have added controls like Html.ValidationSummary and Html.ValidationMessageFor (for each field in your model) and I've been told it's supposed to work like magic!  But it doesn't :(

Any ideas why my validation is not working?  Do I have to do something special because the controls were created dynamically?

Steve

P.S. BTW, the server side validation works, but not the client side.

Comment: I have the same issue you are having but with the Window control.  Any luck?

Comment: No.  Sorry Nick.  I have postponed this issue, but will have to come back to it by the end of the month.  I will post back here when I find out.  Can you do the same if you have any luck on your end?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the datatypes and override the Validate() method on the Model.  And verify casting works with the stored datatypes and the values of the dynamically created controls..  if the cast doesnt work return a validationresult.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer.  The datatypes are already stored.  They are in my model.  Server side validation already works, so why would overriding the Validate method on the model work?